# How can you update bios on p5k-e motherboard without a floppy?

Tags: bios, updates

I have an ASUS P5K-E motherboard and I need to update the bios but I don't have a floppy drive or floppy disks. Is it possible to set up a CD so I can boot from it and flash the bios?

Thanks!

Comment: Aaron's suggestion is the best route to take, but when you have a bios that does not allow updating while in the bios (OEM PC's) see this link on how to make a bootable CD to flash the bios. http://www.biosflash.com/e/bios-boot-cd.htm

Answer (score 2):

The mainboard is pretty new, so you should have two options:

1. Update with a program running on Windows. Just select your version of Windows on the [download page](http://www.asus.com/product.aspx?P_ID=LCK1LS8DWojB38IJ).
2. Put the update file on an USB stick and select it from the update menu in the BIOS.